# Only show first element of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I show only the first element in angular?

I'm using `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-show="$first">
    <div>{{ product.price }}</div>
</div>
```

But since I'm not repeating, then I shouldn't have to use `ng-repeat`? How can I get this to display just the first, without having to go in a ng-repeat?

Comment: In the future, you also have $index available to you. In this case you wouldn't use it, but you could do something like <div ng-show="$index==0">{{ product.price }}</div>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Don't use ng-repeat directive, this should work:

```
<div>{{ products[0].price }}</div>
```

Comment: What if `products` is an empty array?

Answer (score 58):

You might also want to use

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products|limitTo:1">
   <div>{{ product.price }}</div>
</div>
```

but yes the code below is better

```
<div>{{products[0].price}}</div
```

Comment: I like this one since I have a scenario where I (in this case) be using "product" several times. And the full hash is something like bigGroupofthings.mediumGroupofthings.smallerGroupofthings so I don't want to have to type `bigGroupofthings.mediumGroupofthings.smallerGroupofthings[0]` instead of `product` each time!

Comment: `limitTo` should be used as for other solution my directive was not triggering when index 0 changed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
<div ng-bind="products[0].price"></div>
```

It will use the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you can show the last in an array by doing this:

```
<div>{{ products[products.length-1].price }}</div>
```