# angularjs bootstrap carousel not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

## HTML

How can i add **active class** to the first image?
I want to slide images from database but i can't

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">
      <div class="row" id="slider">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="../backend/uploads/{{image.images}}" width="350" height="370">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="discount">
          <h3>Upto</h3>
          <h1>50<small>%</small></h1>
          <h3>Discount</h3>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- row ending -->
    </div>
  </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**JS**
This is my JS code I get data from json

```
var fetch=angular.module("myApp",[])
fetch.controller('slideShowController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  
$http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'getdata.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.images = response.data;
});
```

}]);

Comment: Please show the compiled source code snippet for this.

Comment: You can add class directly in the HTML

Comment: code snippet means..i am new to this world..i didn't understand your question

Comment: If i did that it applied for all the images....I used ng-repeat

Comment: maybe this is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362152/only-show-first-element-of-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any loop that would loop through `image.images` (name implies that this is array of images). Please read about `ngRepeat`.

In the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) there should be possibility to get id of current element. After this you can use if with [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add class `active` if the index is zero (it's first element).

Comment: Yes Zmii this is an php images array

Comment: Please sir help me I can't get any idea

Comment: Try this `src="../backend/uploads/{{image}}"`